# cc1: error: bad value (‘armv8-a’) for ‘-march=’ switch

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

I am currently following [this](https://elinux.org/Jetson/Nano/Upstream) guide and trying to build my u-boot. The issue I am facing is the following error:

```
cc1: warning: unknown register name: x18
cc1: error: bad value (‘armv8-a’) for ‘-march=’ switch
```

This occurs when I run `sudo make O=p3450-000` in my terminal.

I have researched this error however, I feel as those I have properly set my CROSS_COMPILE variable. The following is my GCC version when I run `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/7/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-multiarch --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv5t --with-float=soft --disable-werror --enable-multilib --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabi --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabi- --includedir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
```

I set my CROSS_COMPILE variable by trying the following commands:

```
CROSS_COMPILE=$HOME/l4t-gcc/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-
export CROSS_COMPILE=$HOME/l4t-gcc/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-
```

Neither seem to work.

**Edit**: Using CROSS_COMPILE in my make command seems to have worked.